# Como selecionar um elemento a partir de outro

Tags: jquery

```
<select class="form-control dropup bs-select-hidden" name="sys_nivel_acesso_id">
</select>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control dropup">
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" title="-----">
</div>
```

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda para selecionar via jQuery o elemento `button` a partir do elemento `select` de nome `sys_nivel_acesso_id` com intenção de dar o focus.

Já tentei:

- `$('select[name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"]').next('div button').focus()`
- `$('select[name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"]').next('div').next('button').focus()`

Mas não funcionou.

Comment: Mas você quer que qualquer mudança no `select` dê o `focus`?

Comment: Não, apenas uma simples linha de código para dar o focus.
Exemplo: se fosse p qualquer outro elemento, `$(elemento).focus();`
Como o button não tem nome e nem id, quero preciso pega-lo pelo select que esta acima.

Comment: `$('select[name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"]').next().find('button')` chega pelo que vejo no teu HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o `div` está exatamente depois do `select` então podes usar o [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) que te dá um único elemento, o diretamente a seguir ao `select`. Podes usar o [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) mas ele retorna muitos elementos e vai piorar a performance quando usado com o [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) pois vai invocá-lo para cada elemento encontrado..

```
$('select[name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"]').next().find('button').focus();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ofb5j03v/

Comment: Funcionou 100%! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Faz dessa forma:

```
$('select[name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"]').siblings('div').find('button');
```

Html:

```
  <select class="form-control dropup bs-select-hidden" name="sys_nivel_acesso_id"></select>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control dropup">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" title="-----">Text</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%! Obrigado.